# Unable to add properties to leaflet rectangle, How to resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, draw

```js
    loadGeofencing(geofencingData) {
      var self = this;
      if (geofencingData) {
          geofencingData.forEach(ele => {
            L.geoJSON(ele, {
              style:  ele.properties,
              pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
                  if (feature.properties.type === 'circle') {
                    return new L.Circle(latlng, feature.properties.radius);
                  } else {
                    return new L.Marker(latlng);
                  }
              },
              onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
                  if (feature.properties.type == 'rectangle') {
                    const rectangle = L.rectangle(layer.getBounds(), feature.properties);
                    // Able to see properties inside rectangle
                    console.log('rectangle : ', rectangle);
                    // added created rectangle to the layer, but properties are not attached here.
                    self.editableLayers.addLayer(rectangle);
                  } else {
                    // Circle Polygones added here, those are having properties
                    self.editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
                  }
              },
            });
          });
        }
    },
```

in the above code if I do `this.editableLayers.toGeoJson()` I'm able to see properties for circle polygone, and empty propertes for rectangle.

Any kind of help will much be appreciated.